# What is the correct Python syntax for this?

Tags: python, syntax

I would like to get only the first match if key is in dict. Else I would like to get a NaN. I'm struggling with the correct syntax to fit my needs. The match doesn't have to be in a list, I just need the number. I tried tons of variations...:

```
'Temperatur':[d2.get(key) for key in temperatur if key in d2][0] else None

'Temperatur':d2.get(key) for key in temperatur if key in d2 else None
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict\[key\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `next` with a default:

```
'Temperatur': next((d2.get(key) for key in temperatur if key in d2), None)
```